# Apriori algorithm-difference between A->B and B->A application rule

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, apriori

what is the difference between A->B and B->A application rule..

if transaction database is like this ,

T1 Bread, Jelly, Butter

T2 Bread, Butter

T3 Bread, Butter, Milk

T4 Beer, Bread

T5 Beer, Milk

how to calculate support and confidence of bread->butter and butter->bread ..?

please help me guys..

Comment: Look it up. It's in every book on association rule mining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: this image has the information to get started on it hope it's helpful] which will calculate the Support factor and confidence factor for you. you can read more about that in [here](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/association-rules/).

Comment: thanx frend..its really helpful to me